# Sticky select with data from MySQL in PHP doesn't stick with all data after submitting the form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, select

I've been trying this for hours, and searching around here to find an answer but I couldn't find one.

(I will try my best to explain it clearly) :

My website is about Reports. Each report will have some information that includes the name of the reporter. The reporter can select his/her name from "select" "options" list.

I have another page where the admin can select a report and see who wrote it, and the admin can change the reporter name from the same "select" "option" list.

So, when the admin select a report, the code retrieves the name of the reporter and makes it sticky in the "select" "option" list from the database. Which is good.

Here is the issue with the code:

I have these names "with this order from the database": Adam, Bell, Carlos, David

If the reporter name is Bell, and the admin changes it to Adam, and clicks Submit. If nothing wrong with the form, the form will be submitted correctly. However, if anything else gone wrong with the page info (for example bad phone formatting) the validation will show up, and this is the problem that I've : the name that has been selected is NOT sticky! So, the name will stay Bell NOT Adam

The crazy thing is, if the reporter name is Adam, and the admin changes it to Bell, and clicks Submit. And anything gone wrong with the page info, the name will be sticky with Bell!

The point is:

The name will be sticky if the admin changes the name from "Adam" to Bell, Carlos, or David. Because Adam is the first name of the names order.

If the name is Bell, the name can be sticky if the admin changes it to Carlos or David only (Carlos will be sticky, same thing with David) BUT NOT Adam! Otherwise the name will go back to Bell.

If the name is Carlos, the name can be sticky ONLY if the admin changes it to David (only David will stay sticky, otherwise the name will go back to Carlos)

David Cannot be changed to stay stick with any other name, because it's the last name of the order.

You see the point?

If the name is Carlos, the admin select Bell to change the name, the name will NOT be sticky in the form. It will go back to Carlos. On the other hand, if the name is Carlos, and the admin select David to change the name, the name will be sticky (this is because of the order of the the names I think) or because the "foreach" already passed the names Adam, Bell, so they cannot be sticky when you get to Carlos, however, it's ok for David because David is the last name (comes after Carlos name)

So, what is the problem with my code???

(I'm sorry for the long question, but the problem is complicated as you can see)

```
<?php
                    //check session value:
                    if (isset($_SESSION['report_id'])){
                      $report_id = $_SESSION['report_id'];
                    }
                    else if (isset($_POST['report_id'])){
                      $report_id = $_POST['report_id'];
                    }
                    else{
                      echo "index.php";
                    }

                    //if POST "Update" :
                    if ( ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (isset($_POST['update'])) ) {
                      $username = $_POST['username'];
                      $phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
                      //errors handling :
                      $error = array();
                      if(empty($phone_number)) $error[]= "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible input-sm' role='alert' dir='rtl' style='padding-top: 5px; padding-right: -5px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px'>
                                                        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                                                        <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <strong style='color: #e62e00;'>Warning !</strong> Enter a phone number!
                                                        </div>";

                      if(empty($error)){
                        include("dbc.php");
                        $qq = "UPDATE reports SET username = '$username',
                                                 section_name = '$section_name',
                                                 phone_number = '$phone_number'
                                                 WHERE report_id = '$report_id'";
                        $rr = mysqli_query($dbc, $qq);
                        if($rr){
                          echo "<script>window.open('successful_update.php', '_self')</script>";
                        }
                        else{
                          echo "<div class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible' role='alert'>
                                                                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'>
                                                                    <span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span>
                                                                    </button>
                                                                    <strong>Warning !</strong> Something wrong!
                                                                    </div>";
                        }
                      }
                      else{
                        foreach ($error as $err){
                          echo $err;
                        }
                      }
                    }

                  <form action="report_details.php" method="POST" name="">

                    <?php
                      include("dbc.php");
                      $q = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE report_id = '$report_id'";
                      $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
                      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
                          $db_username = $row['username'];
                          $db_phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
                      }
                    ?>

                    <!-- Username -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label>name:</label>
                      <?php
                        include("dbc.php");
                        $qq = "SELECT DISTINCT username FROM users ORDER BY username";
                        $rr = mysqli_query($dbc,$qq);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rr)){
                          $username_array[] = $row['username'];
                        }
                        echo '<select class="form-control border-input" name="username">';
                                                    foreach($username_array as $user){
                                                        $selected = '';
                                                        if($user == $db_username) {
                                                            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                                                        }
                                                        if($_POST['username'] == $user) {
                                                            $selected = 'selected="selected"';
                                                        }
                                                        echo '<option value="'.$user.'"'.$selected.'>'.$user.'</option>';
                                                    }
                        echo '</select>';
                      ?>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Phone Number -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phone_number">Phone Number :</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone_number" value =
                      <?php if(isset($_POST['phone_number'])) { echo $_POST['phone_number']; } else { echo $db_phone_number; } ?>>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Update Button -->
                    <div class="text-center">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-fill btn-wd" name="update" value="Update">Update</button>
                    </div>

                  </form>
```

Comment: You said the validation causes the error. Can we see your validation code?

Comment: The validation is OK. But the problem can be seen when there is a validation. When you change the name, it cannot be sticky with all names!

Comment: As I said, it will be sticky when you change Adam to any other name because Adam is the first name, so if you change it to Bell, and there is a validation with (phone number for example), you will see the name sticky to Bell. However, the same case doesn't happen when you change to backward order (for example, from Bell to Adam, or David to Carlos)

Comment: _"The validation is OK"_ - Sure, but if we can't see the whole flow, it's hard for us to figure out what's actually happening in your code. We need to see all parts of your code that's related to this in any way.

Comment: The problem is most likely with how you're setting `$db_username`.

Comment: You need to post that code. The code you've posted is very simple and looks fine.

Comment: OK ^_^ I'm updating the code now

Comment: If the name is Carlos, the admin select Bell to change the name, the name will NOT be sticky in the form. It will go back to Carlos. On the other hand, if the name is Carlos, and the admin select David to change the name, the name will be sticky (this is because of the order of the the names I think) or because the "foreach" already passed the names Adam, Bell, so they cannot be sticky when you get to Carlos, however, it's ok for David because David is the last name (comes after Carlos name)

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: Try changing the row: `$db_username = $row['username'];` to `$db_username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $row['username'];`. That way, it will use the posted data instead of the database data, if there is any posted data. Just like you're already doing when you echo the phone number (which you should wrap in quotes when you echo it)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Dude, WaaaaW you just fix it ^_^ Thank you sooooo much my friend. I'm very thankful to you

Comment: I'll write it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: Thank you so much bro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the form is posted, you're getting and using the data from the database instead of the posted data. At least for `username`.

Try changing:

```
$db_username = $row['username'];
```

to

```
$db_username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : $row['username'];
```

This will now use the posted data, if there is any, instead of the database data.

You're actually already doing when you echo the phone number (which you should wrap in quotes when you echo it).

#### A better alternative

You can actually just change this part:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE report_id = '$report_id'";
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
    $db_username = $row['username'];
    $db_phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
}
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // We have no post data, get it from the database
    $q = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE report_id = '$report_id'";
    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        $db_username = $row['username'];
        $db_phone_number = $row['phone_number'];
    }
} else {
    // We have post data, let's use that instead
    $db_username = $_POST['username'];
    $db_phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];
}
```

and then

```
<input type="text" class="form-control border-input" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone_number" value="<?= $db_phone_number ?>" />
```

since you don't need to make that db-call at all if you have post data.